# Is there an illusion in the tutorial area?

Tags: dark-souls-2

At the exit of the tutorial area, there is a big plain wall and a message with 10k upvotes: "illusion ahead, try gesture". Is it trolling or is there actually something there?

[image: screenshot of the message]

Comment: Hi, in case you're wondering: I edited out the tag in the title because the tag already clarifies what game the question is for and in search engines the tag will be shown before the question in the title, so it's unnecessary to put it in front of the question. See this answer: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6950/when-should-we-edit-game-names-out-of-question-titles-and-why/6951#6951

Comment: @Kodama, thanks for clarification! But still, I think the game name in the title is nessesary.

Comment: @klm123 it may be acceptable, but it absolutely not *necessary*. No one will look into "[dark-souls-2] Is there an illusion... ?" in search of answers about HoMM3.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's no illusion in that area. You open hidden walls by pressing X/A on your controller and in very rare cases by attacking a wall or using explosives. I'm afraid you were trolled successfully in this case.

Comment: +1 And now the Wall of Doom will get even more upvotes. Can I downvote the Internet?

Comment: Illusion not ahead, try up vote.

Comment: I think it is worth noting that about half the time those messages are just trolling you. Especially if they say "try <anything that isn't X/A or attacking/explosives>".

Comment: @forgivenson, I've got tons of helpfull messages in this game. Yes, it may be 50% if you take into account "try jumping":) but still 50% is very good, if a message is liying you lose nothing but a few minutes of your time, but if its correct it can be huge deal.

Comment: Yes, agreed, but that doesn't negate what I said. I just thought it would help the OP to know that they should expect to see more messages that prove to be false.